# Convert Pandas DataFrame to nested dictionary where key value pairs are columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns. Say it looks like this:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'key2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    'value': ['a-mapped', 'b-mapped', 'c-mapped', 'd-mapped', 'e-mapped', 'f-mapped', 'g-mapped']
})
```

```
> test_df

    key1    key2    value
0   1       a   a-mapped
1   1       b   b-mapped
2   1       c   c-mapped
3   1       d   d-mapped
4   2       e   e-mapped
5   2       f   f-mapped
6   2       g   g-mapped
```

I would like to return a nested dictionary where the first keys are `key1` and then then the second key value pair would be `{key2: value}`. For example, I would want the `desired_result` to be

```
{
    1: {'a': 'a-mapped', 'b': 'b-mapped', 'c': 'c-mapped', 'd': 'd-mapped'},
    2: {'e': 'e-mapped', 'f': 'f-mapped', 'g': 'g-mapped'}
}
```

I can achieve this by using some loops:

```
desired_result = {}
for key1 in test_df.key1:
    desired_result[key1] = {}
    
for idx, row in test_df.iterrows():
    desired_result[row.key1][row.key2] = row.value
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = test_df.groupby("key1").apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x["key2"], x["value"]))).to_dict()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    1: {"a": "a-mapped", "b": "b-mapped", "c": "c-mapped", "d": "d-mapped"},
    2: {"e": "e-mapped", "f": "f-mapped", "g": "g-mapped"},
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Andrej but using a dictionary comprehension:

```
out = {k: dict(zip(g['key2'], g['value'])) for k, g in test_df.groupby('key1')}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'a': 'a-mapped', 'b': 'b-mapped', 'c': 'c-mapped', 'd': 'd-mapped'},
 2: {'e': 'e-mapped', 'f': 'f-mapped', 'g': 'g-mapped'}}
```

Comment: this is a bit faster than `apply`, as `405 µs` against `523 µs` (on my machine)

Comment: @Roman yes, both are a python loop but `apply` adds an overhead, plus you need to create an intermediate Series to then convert to dict ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
out_d = test_df.set_index('key2').groupby('key1')['value'].agg(dict).to_dict()
Out[14]: 
{1: {'a': 'a-mapped', 'b': 'b-mapped', 'c': 'c-mapped', 'd': 'd-mapped'},
 2: {'e': 'e-mapped', 'f': 'f-mapped', 'g': 'g-mapped'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.set_index("key2")['value'].to_dict()

test_df.groupby('key1').apply(function1).to_dict()
```

out:

```
{1: {'a': 'a-mapped', 'b': 'b-mapped', 'c': 'c-mapped', 'd': 'd-mapped'},
 2: {'e': 'e-mapped', 'f': 'f-mapped', 'g': 'g-mapped'}}
```